# I have a button to display the table in the form but it displaying the table outside the form how can I dis[lay within the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
function boardSize(id, btnid)
    {
        function hitheadr(id,btnid) {

            return function () {
                console.log(id);

          };

        }

        function createTable(rows, cols, element) {
            function getButtonId( ) {

                return 'hit'
           }

            var table = document.createElement('table'),
                tr, td, button, i, j,
                colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];

            for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                tr = document.createElement('tr');

                for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    td = document.createElement('td');
                    button = document.createElement('button');
                    button.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getButtonId(i, j)));
                    button.onclick = hitheadr(getButtonId(i, j));
                    button.id = getButtonId(i, j);
                    button.onclick = onBtnClick;

                    // button.innerHTML = 'HIT';
                    /* document.getElementById(getButtonId(i, j)).onclick = function () {
                     alert('should ');

                     };*/


                    button.id = getButtonId(i, j);
                    td.appendChild(button);
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
                table.appendChild(tr);
                table.setAttribute("align", "center");
                tr.setAttribute("border", "2");
            }
            element.appendChild(table);
        }

        createTable(3, 3, document.body);
        document.getElementById(btnid).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(btnid).style.backgroundColor = "#00CCFF";
        document.getElementById('le').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('se').disabled = true;
    }
```

```
    </tr> </table>

</div>
<div class="content">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>  <input type="button" class="button" name="st"  value= "3*3"  id="re" onclick ="boardSize(1,'re')"  > </td>
```

I have a button to display the table in the form but it displaying the table outside the form  how can I display within the form 
how can I display the content of button within the form help me.

Comment: I can't see a form. I see some invalid HTML though.

Answer (score 1):

In the code your are creating table as the child of body that is why it is appearing in the last outside the form. In createTable function pass the third argument as that form in which you want table to appear. As `createTable(3, 3, document.querySelector('form'))`